# Transposing rows into columns

Tags: sql, oracle, transpose

I have following data

```
with sample_data as (select to_date('05/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, '1' Period, 'A' code from dual union all
                 select to_date('05/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, '2' Period, 'A' code from dual union all
                 select to_date('05/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, '3' Period, 'P' code from dual union all
                 select to_date('05/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, '4' Period, 'A' code from dual union all
                 select to_date('05/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, '5' Period, 'P' code from dual
```

)
select *       from   sample_data

That gives me simple query results as below

```
 DT PERIOD  CODE
2015-01-05 00:00:00 1   A
2015-01-05 00:00:00 2   A
2015-01-05 00:00:00 3   P
2015-01-05 00:00:00 4   A
2015-01-09 00:00:00 5   P
```

I would like to transpose the results like this -

```
DATE           ATTENDANCE
2015-01-05     12345
               AAPAP
```

How can I do that?
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

This is an Oracle SQL question and not PL/SQL!

That could be something like:

```
select to_char(dt,'YYYY-MM-DD') date,listagg(period) within group (order by period)||chr(13)||chr(10)||listagg(code) within group (order by period) attendance
from (

with sample_data as (select to_date('05/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, '1' Period, 'A' code from dual union all
             select to_date('05/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, '2' Period, 'A' code from dual union all
             select to_date('05/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, '3' Period, 'P' code from dual union all
             select to_date('05/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, '4' Period, 'A' code from dual union all
             select to_date('05/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, '5' Period, 'P' code from dual
) select * from sample_data

) group by to_char(dt,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Note that the function listagg only can be used from Oracle 11.2. If you are on an earlier version you can use xmlagg, but thats a bit more clotted.